# Why do atoms absorb photons at specific wavelengths and reflect photons at wavelengths other than the absorbed photons?

Tags: photons, electrons, atoms, wavelength, absorption

As we already know that the electron emits light photons when it travels from one orbit to another, and that causes this transition is the electron absorption of the incoming photon. But when the electron absorbs a photon, it moves to a farther orbit. Does the outgoing photon have a wavelength similar to the wavelength of the incoming photon?

Comment: your title correctly assigns  to atoms the absorption of photons., the content wrongly  just to electrons. It is the total atom that has spectral transitions. Your title mentions reflections, which are different then transitions between orbitals of the atom.

Answer (score 2):

Let me note first that a free electron can never absorb, nor emit a photon due to the restrictions imposed by the energy and the momentum conservation. It can however scatter a photon, which is referred to as *Compton scattering*.

Atoms and solids absorb and emit photons, which often happens due to the transitions of electrons between energy levels (although other scenarios are possible - e.g., emission and absorption due to the rotational or vibrational degrees of freedom in molecules). If a photon is absorbed via an electron transition, the energies of the initial and the final electron states are related to the photon frequency via
$$ \hbar \omega = E_f - E_i.$$
Similar restriction applies when electron jumps from a higher energy state to a lower one. This is why the atomic spectra are composed of discrete lines - they correspond to transitions between different pairs of discrete levels.

Simple light scattering, known as *Rayleight scattering*, does not require a second energy level - it is a second-order ("virtual") process. This is why it can happen at any frequency. It is also worth pointing out the combination of the two: *the Raman scattering* where the photon energy is split into two smaller parts - one is absorbed and the other is emitted as a smaller energy photon (or in the reverse order).

[Here is a Wikipedia figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_spectroscopy#/media/File:Raman_energy_levels.svg) which illustrates the three types of processes described above.

Comment: „a free electron can neither absorb ... a photon„? It’s clear (to me), that photons will accelerate electrons. So at minimum photons partially will be absorbed. Means, the get absorbed and re-emitted with longer wavelength.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler What you are saying is that electron can scatter a photon (and that this scattering can be inelastic). This is what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: thank for your answer but Is it possible for an electron to emit a photon when it travels further?and what is it compton?